# Wait function that stops all running code until the wait function has finished being called?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a wait function that wont call the function and carry on reading the rest of the code, and instead waiting the set amount of time until the next lines of code are executed. I can use an IEnumerator and use `yield return new WaitForSeconds(WaitTime)` but while this is called it will just skip onto the next line of code without waiting for the `WaitForSeconds()` to be finished. Is there any other sort of function?

Comment: If you run that in a coroutine (with `StartCoroutine`), then execution _will_ wait for those seconds (at least the execution of that method). You should show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, you could assign a false value to a bool variable and set it to true when time has passed. In the update method, you go ahead if that variable is true. In pseudocode:

```
bool control=false;

Update()
{
    do something;
    do something;
    call ienumerator();
    if(control)
    {
       do stuff;
    }
}

ienumerator example()
{
    wait seconds;
    control=true;
}
```